# Tessitura of a piece

Tags: vocal-range

How do you find the tessitura of a piece? I know you're looking for the lowest and highest notes but where exactly are you looking for them? Are you looking for the lowest and highest notes in a particular place like the melody or harmony? Or are you looking for the lowest and highest notes in the entire peice?

Answer (score 1):

You're not neccesarily looking for just the highest or lowest notes. If the song has a lot of high notes it's said to have a high tessitura. This doesn't mean that it contains notes that are too high or nearly too high to sing comfortably, but that the voice will be singing towards the top of its range for a fair bit of the song. The same goes for a low tessitura.As far as what proportion of the song - don't know!

Comment: It's too early yet to say accepted answer - there may be better ones after the weekend, when everyone's back at work with nothing else to do!

Answer (score 1):

**The tessitura of an aria/song is where the majority of the notes lie within the range of the Aria/song.**  The *range* is the highest and lowest note.  If the Aria's highest note is A5 (middle C is C4) and the lowest note is A3, that makes the Aria 2 octaves.  That is within a soprano or a mezzo range.  How to tell if the aira belongs to the soprano rep or a mezzo rep?  Look at the *tessitura* of the aria.  If most of the notes are from A4 to A5 then it is soprano aria with some low notes.  If most of the notes *tessitura* are between A4 and A3 then it is a mezzo aria with high notes.
Aristo Vocal Performance Studio

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a good operational definition of tessitura. However, the first thing that comes to mind is to compute (for a piece or collection of pieces) the pitch times the duration of each note. Then the cumulative distribution from lowest to highest notes can be plotted (or tabulated). Next take the 25%-75% sub range (which contains at least half of the note durations) and use that as the basis for the tessitura. Measures within that sub range could be the mean, or median, or mode. (Arithmetic average or midpoint or most common note*duration value respectively.)

The above suggestion is a bit crude in that some pieces may have sections centered around a low note and another section around a high note. Such pieces should probably have two separate measurements. That's a musical not a mathematical judgement.

Likewise, my suggested 25%-75% range may not be best; perhaps 10%-90% or something else. (Again a musical, not a mathematical judgement.)

Comment: I guess 'mode' is closest to what this is. Not heard of duration of notes, only frequency ( as in how often they occur!)

Comment: The little I did find researching automatic tessitura evaluation took durations. The idea is that singing note for 8 beats should count more than singing one for 1 beat. One could weight things differently say by the square root of durations or something.

Answer (score 0):

There's range and there's tessitura.  You know what range is.  Tessitura is more subtle, it's sort of the centre of gravity of the piece.  Like the composer knew where a singer's 'best notes' were and made full use of them.